# retreive a table from another table with key in a column and values in other columns with mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

In mysql I have a table called db1 (82000 rows):

```
id tutor school
---------------
1 tutor1 schoolA
2 tutor2 schoolA
3 tutor3 schoolC
4 tutor2 schoolD
3 tutor2 schoolC
4 tutor2 schoolE
```

---

I want to create another table (to be exported to excel later) which looks like:

### tutor school1 school2 school3 ..

### tutor1 schoolA

### tutor2 schoolA schoolD schoolC schoolE

### tutor3 schoolC

by the way the table was extracted from our ERP to excel I tried to do in excel, it took unlimited time (formula and vba), I guess Excel is not meant for this nor Power BI, so I try mysql and java but I don't know where to start

Comment: Note that, by convention, a column called id is normally a surrogate primary key. And for further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, but consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

the magic sql command group_concat is the answer,
you simply put this query
select tutor, group_concat(school) from db1 group by tutor;

For Mr Strawbery, you may be right about your remark concerning form/shape/display issues but couldn't you please keep those remarks until somebody gives some clues to desperate people like me who were looking for a straw to catch at